# PHP: How do I combine multiple associative arrays into a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Consider three associative arrays in php:

```
$a1 = array(
"a" => "1",
"b" => "2",
"c" => "3"
);

$a2 = array(
"d" => "4",
"e" => "5",
"f" => "6"
);

$a3 = array(
"g" => "7",
"h" => "8",
"i" => "9"
);
```

How would you efficiently combine these into a multidimensional array as follows:

```
$result = array(
"1" => array("4","7"),
"2" => array("5","8"),
"3" => array("6","9")
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something to accomplish your goal?

Comment: What are the rules? Is $a1 providing the keys and $a2/$a3 the values?

Comment: did you mean `"1" => array("1","4","7"),`?

Comment: @castis, no the key should be the the value of the $a1: "1" => array("4","7")

Comment: @MarkBaker - correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to a couple of questions I answered last night:

```
$a1 = array(
"a" => "1",
"b" => "2",
"c" => "3"
);

$a2 = array(
"d" => "4",
"e" => "5",
"f" => "6"
);

$a3 = array(
"g" => "7",
"h" => "8",
"i" => "9"
);

$x = array_combine(
    $a1,
    call_user_func_array('array_map', [null, $a2, $a3])
);
var_dump($x);
```

Comment: Well I prepared the exact same answer, just with an explanation what the code does and now I was waiting for OP to show some effort and some work! But now OP got his candy!

Comment: Perfect! I wish I could award this one to you now! Failed on my server at first due to the old php install. After I accepted the answer, I corrected it to call_user_func_array('array_map', array(null, $a2, $a3)) and it runs great now. It's shorter than what I accepted.

Comment: @MarkBaker http://stackoverflow.com/q/30131528 Do you see more, less or equal amount of effort in OP's new question (compared to this)? Also since he posted this question in this quality he probably assumes that he will get his code with this effort. And exactly this behaviour comes from answering questions like this! (with no effort shown)

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straight forward:

```
foreach($a1 as $val) {
    $result[$val] = array(array_shift($a2), array_shift($a3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
  <?php

$a1 = array(
    "a" => "1",
    "b" => "2",
    "c" => "3"
);

$a2 = array(
    "d" => "4",
    "e" => "5",
    "f" => "6"
);

$a3 = array(
    "g" => "7",
    "h" => "8",
    "i" => "9"
);

$a1_ = array_values($a1);
$a2_ = array_values($a2);
$a3_ = array_values($a3);

$newarray = array();
$max = count($a1_);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    $newarray[$a1_[$i]] = array($a2_[$i], $a3_[$i]);
}

var_dump($newarray);
```

which outputs

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Works, but I have to deal with 30-50 arrays - having to declare $a1_ = array_values($a1);
$a2_ = array_values($a2);
$a3_ = array_values($a3); seems like a drag.

Answer (score 0):

First combine all of the arrays into a single multi-dimensional array.

```
$arrays = array();
array_push($arrays,$a1) //Do the same for the rest
```

Create another array and loop through the one we just created.

```
$result = array();
foreach($arrays as $a) {
    $result[$a[0]] = array_shift($a);
}
```

This pulls the first value out of the array and makes it the key. It then uses array_shift to pop out the first element of the array so it is not included in the assignment.

Is this along the lines of what you are looking for?

Note: This is scaleable for any size array and any number of arrays. Just add any array you want included into $arrays using array_push and it will follow the pattern you outlined above.